# UE4 - FBX -Blender not exporting animations

Tags: animation

I just cannot export blender animations to FBX format

- they do not play in FBX viewer
- they do not appear in Unreal
- no import options are displayed in the FBX import dialog

**I tried exporting selecting the object, the armature, then both**

**also tried different options in the FBX export**

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

edit :

I created another test scene that works, and I noticed that the scene that contains the animation that fails has an NLA displayed in green

how do I remove this ?

[image]

Comment: I never create NLA Track and it works fine for me that way.

Comment: Now I see. You try to reimport an asset which aren't the same as the import. Try to remove the old prop from the UE project, then import the new one.

Comment: I updated my question, there is a green NLA ...while my other simple cube mesh does not have that...

Comment: btw I always remove my previous import before importing in unreal, ..one never knows

Answer (score 1):

apparently a bug in blender 2.9
being investigated

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the "All Actions" button is not exporting ALL or any in some cases of the actions